# Use SecItemUpdate in simulator and get an error -50

Tags: ios, updates, keychain

Can anybody tell me where is the miastake? I have no idea now.

//Get a query Dic

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)keychainQueryDictionary:(NSString *)service
{
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,(__bridge id)kSecClass,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
            nil];
}
```

//Here i save some data to keychain

```
+ (OSStatus)saveData:(id)data service:(NSString *)serviceIdentify
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self keychainQueryDictionary:serviceIdentify];

    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);

    [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    return SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
}
```

//delete opration

```
+ (OSStatus)deleteData:(NSString *)serviceIdentify
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self keychainQueryDictionary:serviceIdentify];
    return SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
}
```

//Here i try to update one item in keychian, but i get an error -50, but i have no idea where is the wrong param

```
+ (OSStatus)updataData:(id)data service:(NSString *)serviceIdentify
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self keychainQueryDictionary:serviceIdentify];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];

    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;
    OSStatus status = errSecNotAvailable;
    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
        NSMutableDictionary *queryDict = nil;
        NSDictionary *ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
        queryDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:ret];
        [queryDict setObject:[keychainQuery objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

        NSMutableDictionary *attributesToUpdate = [self keychainQueryDictionary:serviceIdentify];
        [attributesToUpdate setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

        status = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryDict,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributesToUpdate);
    }

    return status;
}
```

//read opration

```
+ (id)loadData:(NSString *)serviceIdentify
{
    id ret = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self keychainQueryDictionary:serviceIdentify];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;
    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr)   {
        ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-50 is errSecParam. I think you have the parameters flipped for SecItemUpdate. The first param is the search query to find the matching item that needs to be updated. This probably should be created by calling your keychainQueryDictionary method. The second parameter should contain the change - in your example this is the new data for kSecValueData like you are doing, but the dictionary generally doesn't include any of search attributes. In your example it looks like it also contains all the search attributes again which will cause an errSecParam.

As a separate point, also note that any values in the keychainQuery dictionary that are not applicable to the update will also cause errSecParam. If these values are present they can simply be removed, for example:

```
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(keychainQuery, kSecReturnData);
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(keychainQuery, kSecMatchLimit);
```